# FFMPEG Incorrect File Output Path

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I'am working in windows 7 32bit and trying to stream file with ffmpeg, but the output file keep going on wrong location.

If I use this code:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

The output file will be saved in /Users/{username}

If I use absolute path:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy c:/output.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy "c:/output.mp4"
```

It put the file in /Users/{username}/AppData/Local/VirtualStore

So..it is weird and what the heck is the "VirtualStore" folder still a mystery....

My question is simple, how to put output file in desired path location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use '\' insted of '/' the it will move you video to that path

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy "c:\\folder\\output.mp4"
```